# Apache redirect help

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect using a query string and have had no luck...

I am trying to redirect

```
http://www.mysite.com/search/somevalue.html
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.com/search-somevalue/1.html
```

somevaluebeing the query string so whatever value is it will redirect to the new page... any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer so I will answer my question for anyone looking for a similiar answer...

```
RedirectMatch 301 /search/(.*).html /search-$1/1.html
```